# Does StreamController in stateless widget need to be closed?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have this structure (all stateless widgets) :

```
Page1
 Component1
 Component2
Page2
```

In **Page1**, I have this streamcontroller:

```
final _counter = StreamController<int>();
```

And this stream getter :

```
Stream<int> get counterStream => _counter.stream;
```

In **Component1** I can access to `counterStream` and use it in a `StreamBuilder` widget.

Do I risk memory leak if I switch from `Page1` to `Page2` ?

If so, which of these widgets must be statefull in order to dispose something ?

Answer (score 0):

- You should always close a stream when its task is completed. Otherwise memory leak or other performance issues may appear.
- Stream Controller should be in Stateful widget and call it's close method in: the State dispose() callback.
  for example:

  Parent(Statefulwidget)// ex: home page

  - Child(stateless widget): if need the stream -> pass it // sub page
  - Child(stateless widget): if doesn't need the stream -> don't pass it // sub page

**Note:** if your project is huge and you have many streams for example, you can use any state management library like(Provider or Redux) to make it easier